# Invariance of simple functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $(A(s),D(A(s)))_{s\in\mathbb{R}}$ be a family of unbounded operators on a Banach space $X$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow X$ be a simple function, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
g=\sum_{i=1}^n{x_i\textbf{1}_{B_i}},
\end{align*}
where $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_i\in\bigcap_{s\in\mathbb{R}}{D(A(s))}$ (say the intersection is "large" in some sense), $B_i\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ for each $1\leq i\leq n$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. When now applying the family $(A(s),D(A(s)))_{s\in\mathbb{R}}$ to $g$ pointwise, i.e.,
$$h(s):=A(s)g(s)=\sum_{i=1}^n{A(s)x_i\textbf{1}_{B_i}(s)},$$
then $h$ has not to be a simple function anymore, has it? Is there any simple criterion which can decide whether such a family of unbounded operators leaves the simple functions invariant?

Thank you in advance.